# Error with Simultaneous use of Graphics Object in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, gdi+, system.drawing

I am creating a game with two objects on the same form which need to be redrawn separately every few seconds (for animation).  I have one on a separate thread.  Every now and then they produce an error saying that the graphics object is already in use.  The error appears less often because I constructed 2 graphics objects on the same form:

```
Graphics sprite1 = this.CreateGraphics();
Graphics sprite2 = this.CreateGraphics();
```

I then pass these objects to the appropriate method.
I am scared that this is possibly a very bad practice. Any help resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that you're giving those Graphics objects to different threads? I'm pretty sure that part alone is not safe to do, regardless of how many (even 1) Graphics objects you create.

Comment: Yes.  they are sent to different threads.  I need the objects to continue animating at the same time.  One will always be redrawn, the other is only redrawn when the user moves.  Sadly, it occurs at the same time. What would you recommend I do?

Comment: I don't know what I would do, but I *do* know that multi-threaded access to the controls in the .NET framework is not supported, nor safe.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have a problem.  The actual error you are seeing is from code inside GDI+ that ensures the same Graphics object cannot be used in multiple threads.  It is a deeper problem however, you are creating a Graphics object that directly references the window.  The underlying Windows object is a HDC, a handle to a device context.  Device contexts are not thread-safe.  Mishaps are occasional painting artifacts, deadlock and access violations.

You *can* make a Graphics object created by FromImage() image work, as long as they are created from different bitmaps or you make sure two threads don't try to use the same Graphics object at the same time.  That's not going to be terribly useful in game programming.

You can make sprites that draw fast by creating a bitmap with the 32bppPArgb pixel format.  They draw ten times faster than any other format on most machines.  That's as far as you can push it with plain GDI+, the next step up is using a graphics library that uses bitmaps that are resident in video memory and uses the GPU hardware.  Popular managed wrappers for such libraries are XNA, SlimDX and SharpDX.

Answer (score 3):

Usually games are not multi-threaded but have a game-loop. At every iteration, the position of all objects is recalculated according to the current time. Then they are redrawn.

You might consider doing the calculations in a multithreaded way; however, all the drawing should occur in the main thread (the so called UI-thread) inside of the game loop.

---

See chapter "Game structure" in [Game programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Not necessarily. A easy implementation of game multithreading is having a rendering thread and a calculation thread. The rendering thread draws the frame while the calculation thread calculates the next frame. The rendering thread or calculation thread can be tied to each other or not depending on the complexity the programmer wants to deal with. Independent threads need more complexity to stay thread safe while tied threads (one waits for the other) don't need as much complexity.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, `this.CreateGraphics()` is actually creating a reference to the same graphics object, which is the entire form itself.  Threading issues aside, you "can" handle this in your code (in theory) by ensuring that your drawing doesn't go outside pre-defined drawing areas to represent your different screens.  This would involve a bit of hard-coding and is not my style nor preference.

IMHO, a much better method would be to create two Image objects in memory...

```
    Image screen1 = new Bitmap(100, 100); // (width, height)
    Image screen2 = new Bitmap(100, 100); // (width, height)
```

Then you can draw on each image surface separately and use something simple like an image viewer to hold each "view"...

```
    private void DrawGame()
    {
        DrawSprite1(Graphics.FromImage(screen1));
        DrawSprite2(Graphics.FromImage(screen2));
    }
    public void DrawSprite1(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(Pens.Blue, screen1.GetBounds());
    }
    public void DrawSprite2(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillRect(Brushes.Red, screen2.GetBounds());
    }
```

Obviously, this is not the only way to approach this problem, but should be a used as a guide to inspire you towards your own solution. :)